# How to insert a new value to a existing node in firebase?

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I am quite confused about how to insert a new value into an existing node in firebase?

like the pic below, when I try to upload the Route object, I also wanna the uploadedRoute can the Route object's key in. I have tried with setValue, but it will delete the old value, what I want is something like "append" the key, but I really have no idea, could someone give me a hint?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this the kind of structure you would like to get ?

[image]

If so, you may try this :

```
dataRef.child("data/users/\(userID)/Routes/uploadedRoutes/\(routeID)").updateChildValues(["isUploaded": true])
```

Comment: Hello，but in this case, the node is updated to a new value, but not adding the new value into the node(which means the origin value should be kept)

Comment: Could you send a new pic with the firebase snapshot you would like to get ? I'dont really understand your need...

Comment: hello, i mean when I upload to the Firebase, there is a key, for example, the first key is 1, then the uploadedRoutes will get a value of[1], then I upload 2, I want the uploadedRoute store [1,2] , how to realise this?

Comment: @Jenny do you know it is NOT possible to have 2 identical keys in one node? If you want to keep your old key, you should make childByID node inside the parent node. This way you have identical keys, but not in the same node. Maybe you already knew it... just saying